# MySQL confusion

Tags: mysql

I am confused why to this is happening, but when I'm importing a table in, it returns this and the table is empty...

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'all' at line 2
```

Below the message I have this but I'm not sure how to remove the "ALL" or where it came from.

```
SELECT *
FROM `Vehicles`
LIMIT 0 ,
ALL
```

I've tried deleting the table and importing it back again, but the result is always the same.

Here is the table I'm importing:

http://pastebin.com/9PWaix39

Comment: I'm simply importing a table into a database, which contains information of vehicles for a game. The database connects with the script. It worked fine before, but as I've deleted the Vehicles table, and wanted to reimport with new data, I got this.

Comment: No, I haven't wrote it, and it came from nowhere. Now I'm looking on how to fix the error, I suppose removing the ALL bit?

Comment: It didn't "come from nowhere". Somewhere, in your life or in your code, you are appending it to the query. Start there.

Comment: Ok then, Please add these details in your question and post more details about how is this code is generated and other codes involved in this problem so that other users could help you.

Comment: Well, I don't know, I'm a MySQL beginner. I'll paste in the data from the table that I'm importing.

Answer (score 1):

The error has nothing to do with the data you're importing.  The error is indicated in the `SELECT` statement you're using:

```
SELECT *
FROM `Vehicles`
LIMIT 0 ,
ALL
```

What is this query?  Where is it coming from?  Something you have is trying to use this query, and I'm pretty sure that use of `ALL` is invalid.  [Checking the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html), I don't see `ALL` listed as an option for the `LIMIT` clause.  If I were to guess, I'd think that this clause is attempting to get rows beginning at index `0` and continuing for, well, all rows.  If that's the case, the `LIMIT` clause isn't needed in the first place.  The query will by default return all matching rows.  If you did want to match from a given index to all rows, the manual suggests this:

> To retrieve all rows from a certain offset up to the end of the result set, you can use some large number for the second parameter. This statement retrieves all rows from the 96th row to the last:
>
> SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 95,18446744073709551615;

Maybe a different version of MySQL supports the use of `ALL` in a `LIMIT` clause?  If you're using an automated tool which is generating this query then perhaps that tool requires a specific version of MySQL that you're not using.

Comment: Is there anyway I can just delete the ALL? I've just exported the table from a PhpMyAdmin on my computer, the version of it is the latest.

Comment: @HighFlyerPL185: Sure, just remove the `LIMIT` clause entirely: `SELECT * FROM Vehicles`

Comment: When I do this on the database, it just displays the rows of the table. When I do it on the Vehicles table, it displays the above syntax error, where am I going wrong?

Comment: @HighFlyerPL185: I'm not sure what you mean by "when I do this on the database."  The query you've provided seems to have a syntax error based on what I'm seeing in the MySQL manual.  Removing the `LIMIT` clause from that query should get rid of the syntax error (since the clause seems to be unnecessary in this case anyway).

Comment: By "database", I mean when I type this into the query window.